# How can I change the style of the Input Assistant?

Tags: stylesheet, input

I went to the Format/Stylesheet menu item and clicked on ReverseColor. I find the reversed colors more pleasant, with a dark background.

However, the text in the Input Assistant became unreadable. It did not reverse colors. If I hit Esc a then a menu with a white background pops up but the text is so washed out that it is unreadable.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks for any suggestions.